# How to assert not null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm very new in javascript testing, I would like to know how to assert not null in **Mocha** framework.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Mocha supports any assertion library you want. You can take a look at how it deals with assertions here: http://mochajs.org/#assertions. I don't know which one you want to use.

Considering you are using [Chai](http://chaijs.com/), which is pretty popular, here are some options:

> Consider "foo" to be the target variable you want to test

### Assert

```
var assert = chai.assert;
assert(foo) // will pass for any truthy value (!= null,!= undefined,!= '',!= 0)
// or
assert(foo != null)
// or
assert.notEqual(foo, null);
```

In case you want to use `assert`, you don't even need Chai. Just use it. Node supports it natively: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert

### Should

```
var should = require('chai').should();
should.exist(foo); // will pass for not null and not undefined
// or
should.not.equal(foo, null);
```

### Expect

```
var expect = chai.expect;
expect(foo).to.not.equal(null);
// or
expect(foo).to.not.be.null;
```

PS: Unrelated but on Jest there is a `toBeNull` function. You can do `expect(foo).not.toBeNull();` or `expect(foo).not.toBe(null);`

Comment: thanks cause the freakin docs unless I'm missing it don't state you can just do assert(something) for the null & undefined check at the same time.

Comment: Based on Chai's documentation: "Just because you can negate any assertion with .not doesn’t mean you should. With great power comes great responsibility. It’s often best to assert that the one expected output was produced, rather than asserting that one of countless unexpected outputs wasn’t produced. See individual assertions for specific guidance."

Comment: new versions: expect(foo).not.toBeNull();

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me (using **[Expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect)** library with **Mocha**):

```
expect(myObject).toExist('Too bad when it does not.');
```

Comment: Expect belongs to Facebook. Me personally I don't want a FB npm package with access to my filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

In case, you're using Chai in addition to Mocha:

```
assert.isNotNull(tea, 'great, time for tea!');
```

Answer (score 0):

With jest, I had to use:

```
expect(object).not.toExist();
```